# Can we use single snowpipe to load data from multiple source to multiple destination

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can we use a single snowpipe to load data from multiple sources to multiple destinations?

Answer (score 1):

If has a single Copy into command which go from one place to one table.

Aka No

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-pipe.html#create-pipe

I cannot think why you might want a single pipe. Given you billed for work done and if using auto ingestion the files queued.

Comment: It's giving the option for 1 to 1 table mapping how to make it dynamic for 100 tables.

Comment: Ether use an external template/scripting lang or write some Snowflake Scripting to create you 100 pipes DDL.

Comment: As an example you can use a Terraform module to automate the creation of Snowpipes for multiple sources: https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/terraform-snowflake-storage-integration